# passing argumets in between functions

Tags: c, arrays, variables, pointers

I'm working on a program, in which I can not use global variables, etc. It is a school project about generating DNA structures, etc... My problem is, that I do not know, how to pass variables in between several functions. Here, in the following code is one of my functions, which reads a file and stores DNA in the array "pole". Also it increases the variable "i" every time it reads a valid character from the file.

```
    int nacitanie(){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("DNAsekvencia.dat", "r");
    if((fp = fopen("DNAsekvencia.dat", "r")) == NULL)
    {
            printf("Neotvoreny subor");
            fflush(stdout);
    }

    int a, i=0, x=0;
    char z, pole[1000];

    //citanie DNA zo suboru
    while((z = getc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        pole[i] = z;
        i++;
    }
    for(a=0; a<i; a++){
        if(pole[a] == 'A' || pole[a] == 'C' || pole[a] == 'G' || pole[a] == 'T' || pole[a] == 'a' || pole[a] == 'c' || pole[a] == 'g' || pole[a] == 't'){
            x++;
        }else{
            x--;
        }
    }
    if(x==a){
        printf("Sekvenciu sa podarilo nacitat\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    }else{
        printf("Sekvencia nesplna podmienky\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    if(fclose(fp) == EOF)
    printf("Subor sa nezatvoril");

    return 0;
}
```

My other function is histogram, which needs to use that array "pole" and "i" from previous function.
How do I do this? I tried to do it with pointers but not working. Any ideas? I am new into this.

```
    int histogram(){

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("DNAsekvencia.dat", "r");
    if((fp = fopen("DNAsekvencia.dat", "r")) == NULL)
    {
            printf("Neotvoreny subor");
            fflush(stdout);
    }
    int h, a, c, g, t;
    for(h=0; h<i; h++){
        if(pole[h] == 'A' || pole[h] == 'a'){
            a++;
        }else if(pole[h] == 'C' || pole[h] == 'c'){
            c++;
        }else if(pole[h] == 'G' || pole[h] == 'g'){
            g++;
        }else if(pole[h] == 'T' || pole[h] == 't'){
            t++;
        }
    }
    printf("A: %d\n", a);
    fflush(stdout);

    printf("C: %d\n", c);
    fflush(stdout);

    printf("G: %d\n", g);
    fflush(stdout);

    printf("T: %d\n", t);
    fflush(stdout);

    fclose(fp);
    if(fclose(fp) == EOF)
        printf("Subor sa nezatvoril");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the code is opening a file twice with no intervening close: fp = fopen("DNAsekvencia.dat", "r"); and the following line. suggest removing this line.

Comment: the code is closing a file trice with no intervening open: fclose(fp); and the following line.  suggest removing this line.

Comment: I do not understand what exactly do you mean. Which line should I remove and why? ..please explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send pointer to variable to your functions like this:

```
void f(int *a) {
    (*a)++;
}

void g(int *a) {
    (*a)++;
}

int main(void) {
    int a = 0;
    f(&a);
    g(&a);
    printf("%i", a);

    return 0;
}
```

The `printf` result will be: 2

Comment: So and if I use an array, eg. array[a], do I put * in front of the a? array[*a] ?